# How can I create different Json responses to serve different client versions in API?

Tags: java, json, rest, version

I am developing an API and now I have a problem and can't figure out how to solve it. I use Java Play Framework. Until now I always used my entity classes to be serialized and deserialized in Json. Now, I have to remove a field to improve req response time. The problem is, that I still need to send this field to users with old versions, but to users with new versions I would want to use a JsonIgnore annotation.

A simple example:

```
    public class Wallet {
        private long id;
        private User user;
        private BigDecimal patrimony;
}
```

And for new versions, I want these object:

```
    public class Wallet {
        private long id;
        private User user;
}
```

I searched a lot and could not find a pratical example.

Comment: Just use another endpoint like `/wallet` and `/v2/wallet`

Comment: The problem in this is that the code would grow exponentially.

Comment: If you use Jackson for JSON handling you could annotate the `patrimony` property with `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` and it will be included in the JSON only if it has a value

Comment: I think that is not the logic. I have to control the way the json goes in the response. It depends on the version of the client.